# Issue with Relative Paths for Images in Vite+React App Deployed on GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, vite, github-pages

I'm facing a problem with deploying my Vite+React application to GitHub Pages. I have a folder named **flags** inside the **public** directory, which is at the root level of my project, on the same level as the **src** directory. I'm dynamically loading images using the path `<img src="/flags/${filename}.svg">`, and this works perfectly fine on my local development server.

However, after deploying to GitHub Pages, the images are located at the following URL: `maciejkrolpl.github.io/car-plates/flags/poland.svg`. This is expected, but the issue is that in my code, I am referencing the images with the path `maciejkrolpl.github.io/flags/poland.svg`.

Here is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/car-plates/',
})
```

I need assistance in resolving this path issue so that my application can correctly reference the images on GitHub Pages. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried changing `base` entry in vite.config as well as changing location of public directory, but whithout success.

Comment: “and this works perfectly fine on my local development server.”

It is a vite bug. 3 months ago, I sent it to [Nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/22107) and it was labeled **vite** **bug**

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090801/9339427)

I was able to solve the problem using this post. I changed my local paths with adding dot:

```
<img src="/flags/${filename}.svg">
```

In root folder i created `.env.local` file with content:

`PUBLIC_URL=`

In github repository settings I added environment secret with name `PUBLIC_URL` and value `car-plates`

```
PUBLIC_URL=car-plates
```